# Running wrapped OpenMP code only uses 1 thread in service

Tags: multithreading, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to run a calculation in a service that uses a C++/CLI wrapper around code that uses OpenMP to parallelise itself.

The problem is that the OpenMP code is only using a single thread, which drastically increases the time taken. I have tried it in a simple console application to verify that it uses all of the cores.

I have other code in another service that uses TPL's `Parallel.For`, which works great.

Any help, or ideas, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

**UPDATE:** `Environment.ProcessorCount` returns the correct number. Interesting...